# passive form of "recruit" followed by "in" or "into"

Tags: prepositions

> A total of 100 patients were recruited ___ the study.

Do I have to say *recruited **into** the study* or *recruited **in** the study*?

Comment: For most purposes, both seem fine to me. But suppose the purpose of the study was to examine some aspect of how doctors recruit patients into medical study programs, for example (i.e. - the patients are almost incidental, since what you're actually studying is the doctors), I think in that case only ***in*** would work. Compare *10 people were **tricked into** the study* (if they hadn't been conned into it, they might not have agreed to participate), and *10 people were **tricked in** the study* (any number of participant subjects might have watched videos of those 10 deceptions, say).

Answer (score 4):

Several propositions are possible here, depending on what you want to say. If you mean students were sought out in order to participate in the study, use *for*.

If you mean the study itself was used to recruit students for something else, you can use *by* or *with* or *in*. In my mind, *by* implies something more deliberate, whereas *with* and especially *in* imply a more incidental occurrence (as in, "Hey, this guy in this study we are doing would be great to use for this other job/study/whatever.").